# AspNet Core + Hangfire: Job throwing JobLoadException

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, hangfire

everybody

I have a DotNet Core 3.1 app that was created only to run scheduled tasks using Hangfire. There was just one scheduled task and it run properly. But when I added a second task, it started to pop the following exception on Hangfire Dashboard:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Recurring job can't be scheduled, see inner exception for details.
> ---> Hangfire.Common.JobLoadException: Could not load the job. See inner exception for the details.
> ---> System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'SolutionName.AutoUploadService.Jobs.VerifyAuthOnSsoJob' from assembly 'SolutionName.AutoUploadService, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
> at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetType(QCallAssembly assembly, String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, ObjectHandleOnStack type, ObjectHandleOnStack keepAlive, ObjectHandleOnStack assemblyLoadContext)
> at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetType(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase)
> at System.TypeNameParser.ResolveType(Assembly assembly, String[] names, Func`4 typeResolver, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) at System.TypeNameParser.ConstructType(Func`2 assemblyResolver, Func`4 typeResolver, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) at System.TypeNameParser.GetType(String typeName, Func`2 assemblyResolver, Func`4 typeResolver, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) at System.Type.GetType(String typeName, Func`2 assemblyResolver, Func`4 typeResolver, Boolean throwOnError) at Hangfire.Common.TypeHelper.DefaultTypeResolver(String typeName) at Hangfire.Storage.InvocationData.DeserializeJob() --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at Hangfire.Storage.InvocationData.DeserializeJob() at Hangfire.RecurringJobEntity..ctor(String recurringJobId, IDictionary`2 recurringJob, ITimeZoneResolver timeZoneResolver, DateTime now)
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> at Hangfire.Server.RecurringJobScheduler.ScheduleRecurringJob(BackgroundProcessContext context, IStorageConnection connection, String recurringJobId, RecurringJobEntity recurringJob, DateTime now)

Next you can see the Hangfire configurations:

```
// Other namespaces
using Hangfire;
using Hangfire.SqlServer;

namespace SolutionName.AutoUploadService
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
        public IWebHostEnvironment Environment { get; }

        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IWebHostEnvironment environment)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
            Environment = environment;
        }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllers();

            string connectionString = SteeltoeConfigManager.GetConnectionString(Configuration, "DefaultConnection");
            services.AddDbContext<SolutionContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));

            // Other stuffs

            services.AddHangfire(hangFireConfig =>
            {
                hangFireConfig.SetDataCompatibilityLevel(CompatibilityLevel.Version_170)
                              .UseSimpleAssemblyNameTypeSerializer()
                              .UseRecommendedSerializerSettings()
                              .UseSqlServerStorage(connectionString, new SqlServerStorageOptions()
                              {
                                  CommandBatchMaxTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
                                  SlidingInvisibilityTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
                                  QueuePollInterval = TimeSpan.Zero,
                                  UseRecommendedIsolationLevel = true,
                                  DisableGlobalLocks = true
                              });
            });

            services.AddHangfireServer();
        }

        #pragma warning disable
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseHangfireDashboard();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });

            HangfireJobScheduler.Schedule<VerifyAuthOnSsoJob>(Cron.MinuteInterval(5));
            HangfireJobScheduler.Schedule<UploadReportsJob>(Cron.MinuteInterval(5));
        }
    }
}
```

```
using SolutionName.AutoUploadService.Interfaces;
using Hangfire;

namespace SolutionName.AutoUploadService.Jobs
{
    public class HangfireJobScheduler
    {
        public static void Schedule<TJob>(string cronExpression) where TJob : IJob
            => RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate<TJob>(GetJobName<TJob>(), job => job.Start(), cronExpression);

        public static void Destroy<TJob>()
            => RecurringJob.RemoveIfExists(GetJobName<TJob>());

        private static string GetJobName<TJob>() 
            => typeof(TJob).Name;
    }
}
```

The two jobs I'm trying to put as recurring jobs inherit from IJob:

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SolutionName.AutoUploadService.Interfaces
{
    public interface IJob
    {
       Task Start();
    }
}
```

And a last question: How many servers should it has on HangFire Dashboard Servers page? Even with just one rucurring job running, it shows two servers.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because there were two applications pointing to the same database. That´s the reason for the two servers I mentioned at the end of question. The first was running on a different machine and it was set to use only 1 worker. The second it's the app I was running at localhost. I got the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69800085/4727416